# BackgroundSubtractorGMG without Kalman filter?

Tags: c++, opencv

On Opencv I’ve read that BackgroundSubtractorGMG comes from article "Visual Tracking of Human Visitors under Variable-Lighting Conditions for a Responsive Audio Art Installation," A. Godbehere, A. Matsukawa, K. Goldberg, American Control Conference, Montreal, June 2012.

I read it and then I gave a look at OpenCv’s source code.

I’ve not found the part titled “III. MULTIPLE VISITOR TRACKING” on the article (kalman filters).
Furthermore it seemed to me that every pixel is updated, even the ones labelled as foreground (differently from what stated on the article).
If so, that implementation would be just like other methods of OpenCv, but with a slightly different way of storing a memory of past pixels.
Am I wrong somewhere?

**EDIT**
In the original article, which I’ve read carefully, there is a diagram that explains how the algorithm works. (the article is clear, my doubts were about OpenCv's Implementation of it)

Figure 1.
Image & (previous image+foreground pixels) => segmentation part => multitracking part => foreground pixels

What characterizes the original algorithm from other ones is just the embedded multitracking part.
If you want you can remove it, but it won’t make sense anymore.
Anyway it’s not possible to implement that part (which should be really really difficult), without modifying the first part as well, as they are integrated.

Comment: Good point, I'll have to look into OpenCV implementation to check. OpenCV might implement only a “static” version of the algorithm, which utilizes only the top row of the block diagram in
Figure 1. But it's just a guess.

Comment: If I remember well, the code was provided directly by one of the authors. And I can't explain why he gave a depleted version of it. Maybe simply because reordering his own code for inclusion in the package is time consuming. Just one thought: many people use classes and functions without knowing what they do. You’ll expect that hundreds of people will notice what is inside the hood, but usually only bugs are pointed out. The class we are talking about, in its current implementation, simply does what prevoius methods do, and is more sensitive to noise.

Comment: Again, the paper describes a tracking algorithm. I believe that BackgroundSubtractorGMG is a part of this algorithm that does foreground segmentation (no tracking). I don't how this algorithm compares to others without an extensive literature review / testing.

Comment: you can contact the authors of the article for the full source code

Comment: I thought I was clear: in the original algorithm you can’t separate the 2 parts as they should be integrated. I think the author modified it before sharing. I contacted him but I haven’t received any answers. Probably he is involved in a different job now. For a comparison of the complete algorithm just read the last page of the article and for a comparison of the OpenCv algorithm just run it at least 2 seconds in whatever situation, you will notice many artefacts due to noise appearing and disappearing.

Comment: Nope, you CAN separate 2 parts in in the original algorithm, even the authors in the paper describe it.

Comment: The authors talk about a “static” version. They write: “In the “static” version, the background model is not updated selectively, and no dynamical information is used.” The selectively updated background occurs in the first part. Probably they used the “static” (i.e. modified version) for testing purposes and then shared it.

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundSubtractorGMG doesn't implement tracking, it only implements foreground detection. So object tracking is a separate operation on top of the foreground detection. You can implement the tracking part of the paper yourself using [the Kalman filter class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman%20filter#KalmanFilter) in OpenCV.

**Edit** Foreground segmentation and object tracking are two distinct steps of the algorithm proposed in the paper and foreground segmentation is only a part of the algorithm diagram presented in Figure 1. From the article (emphasis is mine):

> *Abstract*—For a responsive audio art installation in a skylit atrium,
> we introduce a single-camera statistical segmentation and tracking
> algorithm. *The algorithm combines statistical background image
> estimation, per-pixel Bayesian segmentation, and an approximate
> solution to the multi-target tracking problem using a bank of Kalman
> filters and Gale-Shapley matching.*
>
> ...
>
> III. MULTIPLE VISITOR TRACKING
>
> Lacking camera calibration, we track
> foreground visitors in the image plane rather than the ground plane.
> *Once the foreground/background segmentation algorithm returns a set of
> detected visitors, the challenge is to track the visitors to gather
> useful state information: their position, velocity, and size in the
> image plane.*
>
> ...
>
> Given this linear model, and given that observations are correctly
> matched to the tracks, a *Kalman filter bank solves the multiple target
> tracking problem*.

So `BackgroundSubtractorGMG` is the foreground/background segmentation algorithm that returns a set of detected visitors. It consists of *statistical background image estimation, per-pixel Bayesian segmentation*.

Part III of the paper focuses on tracking after the foreground objects had been segmented out. It utilizes *an approximate solution to the multi-target tracking problem using a bank of Kalman filters and Gale-Shapley matching.*

Comment: The article describes an embedded multitracking system which is fundamental to help deciding what is foreground and what is background.
The final output is anyway a foreground detection and deciding what to do with it is up to the user, but the described algorithm do implement a Kalman filter bank and it should be a fundamental part of it (the real achievement over past approaches).
Furthermore only pixels that are not considered foreground contribute to update the BG model. Having browsed the source code a little bit I’ve not found this aspect too.

Comment: I also preferred to edit my post to specify some points in detail.